# Serve a minimise prototype.js file with Google AJAX Libraries API?

Tags: prototypejs, cdn, minimize

Is Google AJAX Libraries API offering a way to serve framework file in minimize way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries themselves are served minified by default.

Unfortunately, Google does not serve gzipped versions.

Answer (score 0):

If not, and if I get what you're asking, you could [minify](http://www.vlead.in/resources/tools/minify-javascript/) the JS yourself.